# How to link phone number to already logged in firebase gmail user

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

How to use firebase linkWithCredential? I'm trying to link the phone number to the current firebase user. My problem is linkWithCredentials has an error of `The method 'linkWithCredential' isn't defined for the type 'Function'` Is this because of my version of firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+3? Or I am doing it wrong.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.linkWithCredential(phoneCredential);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of the version.
`.currentUser` is a method in `version 0.15.5+3`. [Link](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/0.15.5+3/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html)

You need to call the method to get the `FirebaseUser` instance.

So your code becomes as shown below:

```dart
await (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).linkWithCredential(phoneCredential);
```